# Latest SVGLIB Python Package Renders Images in Black and White and Font Errors

Tags: python, svg, python-3.6

I have been using SVGLIB 0.8.1 for a few years now to incorporate existing color SVG chart images (created in R) into a PDF file. It has worked great.

When I try to upgrade to the latest SVGLIB 0.9.2, on a clean Windows machine with Python 3.6.1, my imported SVG images (whic are fine themselves) now appear in black and white once imported in the PDF file.

I also get this error when executing SVGLIB commands:

Unable to find a suitable font for 'font-family:Nimbus Sans L'

I really would like to upgrade SVGLIB. What am I doing wrong here?

Simply upgrading to SVGLIB 0.9.2 causes the process of importing SVG images into PDFs to break. Downgrading back to 0.8.1 returns everyuthing to normal.

```
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg
my_canvas = canvas.Canvas(strLinuxMultiserverReportTemporaryFilename)
my_canvas.setPageSize((11.5*inch, 40*inch))
drawing = svg2rlg(image_path)
drawing.transform = (0.25,0,0,0.25,0,0)
intHeaderIndex = 2850
my_canvas.drawString(350, intHeaderIndex, 'System Performance Report')
renderPDF.draw(drawing, my_canvas, intCurrentColumnNumber, intCurrentRowNumber)
my_canvas.save()
```

I expect my nice color SVG files to be imported into the PDF file by SVGLIB and stay in color.

Comment: I'd advise you to report your issue to the maintainers [but you already have](https://github.com/deeplook/svglib/issues/211)